# Hide userform in VBA in order to work with data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a following problem. I would like to hide a userform in order to work with data in worksheet.

I would like to enable user to get back to application.
So I thought if there is a possibility to move userform down on the screen and activate workbook. 
Afterwards the user could drag userform back in the middle of the screen and work with it again.

Does anyone have an experience with something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `me.hide` to hide userform, retaining all values entered into the form. Use `me.show` to bring back the userform to the screen.

This is different from `unload me`, which unload the userform from memory, destroying all values entered. Calling the form again will start the form a new.

If you want the form to be still visible and allow user to interact with worksheet behind, then set the `ShowModal` property to False.. The default is True.

Comment: Thank you, I have not worked with      ShowModal before - really useful! Awsome! Thank you

Comment: Good answer: and here's an additional tip for process designs which involve hopping between the worksheet and the form - consider writing event procedures or macros in the data sheet which detect task completion (or data errors) and bring the userform back to visibility (or back in focus if it's non-modal) with the next button or list selector in the process highlighted and ready to use.  But do, please, check that you're not perpetrating an annoying 'steal the focus' interface that interferes with something else the user's typing.

Comment: thanks for the tips @Nile. You are right, while automation is good for users, its important to take 'friendliness' into consideration as well.