# How to retain the value in textbox when the form gets reloaded

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple vba macro app consisting of 2 textboxs and command button. The idea is the user needs to input numeric value in textboxes and then clicks the button to disable it so they can't change the value. When the form gets reloaded, the numeric value gets lost and I have to re-input another value.

What I want is when the form reloaded,the numeric value will stay.

```
Private Sub btnLock_Click()

txtApple.Enabled = False
txtBanana.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

***Image***

[[image: 1]]

[image]

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34942338/5332500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember that you have, what is essentially, a database at your disposal with the workbook itself.

My suggestion is, when the user adds the value and clicks the button, insert that value into a worksheet (with which you may need to secure, hide, etc. ... or not for that matter) and then get that value back from the worksheet when the form is opened again.

You essentially just need to put the value somewhere that you can get it from again when the form reappears.  If you don't like the worksheet approach then there's always a database, file on the workstation, memory, etc.

Something like this ...

```
Private Sub btnLockBox_Click()
    Sheet1.Range("A1") = txtNumber.Text
    txtNumber.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    txtNumber.Text = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    If txtNumber.Text <> "" Then
        txtNumber.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

I hope I've understood your requirement properly and I hope that approach helps.

Comment: Hi Skin..Thank you so much..that is what I really wanted..How did you add a video to your post..I'll show you mine too..Actually I was able to figure it out what to do but I'll show you mine.

Comment: @theserverguy, it's free downloadable called Screen to GIF.

Comment: I added a gif already. Please see. I still need to add a bit of feature of this app. I need that the user cannot edit Sheet1 so that they cannot edit/change any value.