# How to save listbox values (multiselect) when closing a form?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form with a listbox (MultiSelect). ListBox acts as an autofilter on the "Filter" sheet. How to save ListBox values when closing a form? How to make that when opening a form, the ListBox values are all selected - by default? And how to make the autofilter range determined by itself? Now the range is set manually:

```
With Sheets("Filter").Range("$A$2:$A$2355").
```

To determine the range, I tried to apply the following code:

```
Sheets("Filter").Range("a3:a" & Sheets("Filter").Range("a" & Sheets("Filter").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

...but there was an error.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  With ListBox1
       .AddItem "One"
       .AddItem "Two"
       .AddItem "Three"
       .AddItem "Four"
       .AddItem "Five"
       .AddItem "Six"
       .AddItem "Seven"
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Arr()
Dim Str$, i%, u%
u = 0
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ReDim Preserve Arr(u)
        Arr(u) = ListBox1.List(i, 0)
        u = u + 1
    End If
Next i
With Sheets("Filter").Range("$A$2:$A$2355")
    If u = 0 Then .AutoFilter Field:=1: Exit Sub
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(Arr), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at this, different control, same concept ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204847/how-to-retain-the-value-in-textbox-when-the-form-gets-reloaded/56205716#56205716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do exactly this, and the solution is similar to Skin's - just save the values on your form in a separate (probably hidden) sheet after people update the form

```
 Sheets("Selection").Range("f3") = UserFormData.Divisioncbo.Value
```

and then when they reopen the form make it update , based on those values

```
 UserFormData.Divisioncbo.Value = Sheets("Selection").Range("f3")
```

Regarding the range for your filter, I think you have essentially the same issue as I had - trying to determine a range of an unknown length and then use it as a list that users can select from?
 I added a list to the name manager called `PeopListname
    =OFFSET(Lists!$M$3,0,0,COUNTA(Lists!$M:$M)-1,1)`
and then made this the row source on the VBA userform
=`PeopListname`